# "Find in project as text" in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode4

hii every one

in xcode4 where can i get the option "find in project as text" i mean i need to find a variable in the whole project  ,like how we were doing in xcode3 by right click on the variable--> find in the project--> as text

thanx in advance

Comment: Please take care to use more descriptive subject lines. "problem with xcode" is too vague to distinguish from other questions.

Answer (score 12):

shift + command + f will find in workspace